# Can I have a QR code that will create a contact on the device?

Tags: mobile-phone, barcode-scanner, qr-code

Is it possible to create a QR code, that when scanned, will create a contact on the device?

I tried NeoReader - it only scans the data (string value)

I can print my Blackberry data, and that will add my BB to any other BB that scans it.

Is it possible to have something generic?

Is there an application that can perform that?

*I am ignoring the multi platform for now, so either a iOs or android solution is sufficient now.

thanks

Comment: I now see my answer was not clear. I am/was not looking for a specific app, but more to the technical aspect if it can be done. I did get my answer, that a specific application needs to be written for it. that takes away the generic-ism (wording?) I was hoping to get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, because a QR code is just data, in a format that's easy to scan.  What is done with the data is up to the application that's scanning it.  You'd have to either find or write an application that would create an address book entry when it scanned a QR code containing an address.  If you don't control the devices and applications that will be scanning the QR code, then you can't do it.